# Aumentar velocidade durante o jogo

Tags: libgdx

Boa noite , estou com esse código e queria saber como aumento a velocidade do jogo conforme o tempo vá passando , ou usando pontuação , obrigado

https://pastebin.com/mizhi4UW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faz o seguinte amigo, na parte do código que está o estado do jogo == 1,coloca conorme vou colocar embaixo.
if (estadoJogo == 1) {
if(pontuacao > [pontuação que você desejar em inteiro]){

posicaoMovimentoCanoHorizontal -= deltaTime * [aqui numero inteiro maior que 300]

}
}

}

Comment: Valeu mano , deu certo !!